# Calculating the Positive scores only AND changing the result of the Average from Integer to Float

Tags: c

Here is my code in C, I need help with how to ignore the negative numbers in the **printf("You entered %d scores.\n", i);** and in the **average result**.
Also how to change **int average;** to **float average;** because I don’t get the right average when I change it to float.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
int i, score, sum=0, n;
int average;

for(i=0; score>0; i++)
{
    printf("Enter score (4-10) :");
    scanf("%d", &score);
    if(score>0){
            sum = sum + score;

    }
}



 printf("You entered %d scores.\n", i);
 average = sum / i;
 printf("the average is: %d", average);
}
```

## The required Output:

The program calculates the average of scores you enter.
End with a negative integer.
Enter score (4-10):7
Enter score (4-10):8
Enter score (4-10):9
Enter score (4-10):10
Enter score (4-10):4
Enter score (4-10):4
Enter score (4-10):5
Enter score (4-10):-1
You entered 7 scores.
Average score: 6.71

Comment: `sum / i` is integer division.  Try `1.0 * sum / i`

Comment: Probably ought to change average and sum to floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the average, sum, and scores should all be decimal values (floats).

That means you have to change the scanf argument as well and the printf argument.

When dividing the integer i into the float sum, there is no need to multiply by 1.0, as long as sum is a float.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  float score;
  float sum = 0;
  float average;

  for (i = 0; score > 0; i++) {
    printf("Enter score (4-10) :");
    scanf("%f", &score);  // accept decimals in the scores
    if (score > 0) {
      sum = sum + score;

    } else {
      break; /// leave the loop here to prevent incrementing i
    }
  }

  printf("You entered %d scores.\n", i);
  average = sum / i; // as sum is a float, this division will now work.
  printf("the average is: %2.2f", average); // print 2 decimal places as a float
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
int i, score = 1, n;
float sum = 0.0, average;  //<-------------changed to float

for(i=0; score>0; i++)
{
    printf("Enter score (4-10) :");
    scanf("%d", &score);
    if(score>0){ 
            sum = sum + score;
    }
    else{
       break;
    }
}



 printf("You entered %d scores.\n", i);
 average = sum / i;
 printf("The average is: %f", average); //<--- changed to %f you can use &.2f to print 2 digits after . 

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP indicates that he needs average to be a float